# Proper way of adding multiple parameters for a jquery function to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parameters

I am new to jquery and im trying to create a web client for a mobile social network. I would like to allow users to approve friend requests without refreshing, but the api request for approving a friend request requires 3 parameters to be successful. So how am i suppose to go about hiding these parameters in the html so that i can grab them via jquery when the button is pressed?

Comment: This is question is very vague. I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you talking about modifying HTML in conjunction with AJAX via jQuery?

Comment: where do you have these parameter values on page?

Comment: thats what im asking , i can put them where ever i want. im the one making up the feed of pending requests. i know i can set the id of the button and that takes care of one param , but what about the other 2? whats the proper way of storing several parameters

Answer (score 2):

Are you want to make some server post back (to perform the request approval) and you need this without refreshing the page?

If this is the case use AJAX, you can do server post back without refreshing the page and manipulate the HTML tags. Regarding the parameter you can send more then three parameters in AJAX call.

Here is a sample of jQuery AJAX.

```
$.post("test.php", "{para1: "para1Value", para2: "para2Value", para3: "para3Value"}",
        function(data) { alert(data); },
        "json"
    );
```

Guess you are asking this. :)

---

Below is reply for your comment:

To store the param in HTML property:

**1.** Create a function which get and set the value with passed argument

```
function myParas(para1,para2,para3)
{
this.para1=para1;
this.para2=para2;
this.para3=para3;
}
```

**2.** create a new object of myParas object and pass values to the parameters

```
var myObj=new myParas("para1Value","para2Value","para3Value");
```

**3.** access the property of the object and get the values

```
    myObj.para1 //<= value will be para1Value
    myObj.para2 //<= value will be para2Value
    myObj.para3 //<= value will be para3Value
```

Comment: no , im asking how to store the params in the html properly. say i need to store 3 different params for each firend request that can be retreived when the button is clicked .

Comment: hi I have added your reply in above. If this is your answers don't forget to mark as Answer. :)